# Multiple input save one input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Input section like i want to pass this 3 value in one input value with onchange

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function updateInput($i){
     $('updateval').val($i);
     }
</script>

<input type="text" onchange="updateInput(this.value)" >
<input type="text" onchange="updateInput(this.value)" >
<input type="text" onchange="updateInput(this.value)" >
<input type="text" id="updateval" >
```

i want to show   here the all 3 value and with a seperation

> like value1:value2:value3

in my last input section

Answer (score 0):

1. Give the 3 input id not name, eg v1,v2,v3
2. onchange jquery those 3 input value. $('#updateval').val( [ $('#v1').val(),$('#v2').val(),$('#v3').val()].join(':'));

You're missing the position of source input on your function.

Input without name not passed in form submitted, except you send itvia coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function updateInput(){
     var val1 = $('#value1').val();
     var val2 = $('#value2').val();
     var val3 = $('#value3').val();
     var output = val1 + ':' + val2 + ':' + val3
     $('#updateval').val(output);
 }
</script>

<input id="value1" type="text" Onkeyup="updateInput(this.value)" >
<input id="value2" type="text" Onkeyup="updateInput(this.value)" >
<input id="value3" type="text" Onkeyup="updateInput(this.value)" >
<input type="text" id="updateval" value="">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcfgpwh1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class='val' >
<input type="text" class='val' >
<input type="text" class='val' >
<input type="text" id="updateval" >
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.val').on('keyup',function(){
            let out=''
            $(".val").each(function() {
                   out+= $(this).val()+":";
            });
            $('#updateval').val(out);

        })
     })
    </script>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbg9pzj4/)

Answer (score 0):

Details commented in demo.

```js
// Reference the first form on page
const form = document.forms[0];
/*
Register form to the input event (or change event with .onchange)
The input event will fire immediately after the user has entered any data
The change event will fire when the user has entered data then triggers a blur event by 
focusing elsewhere.
*/
form.oninput = display;

/*
//A Pass Event Object
/*
B1 event.currentTarget is the tag registered to event (form)
B2 .elements.text is a collection of all the form controls [name=text] (inputs)
B3 brackets and spread operator convert collection into an array [...all input] 
B4 .map() returns each input value into an array
*/
/*
//C Get output.all and assign its value to the new array then convert it into a string 
    delimited by colons
//D End function
*/
function display(event) {//A
  let texts = [...event.currentTarget.elements.text].map(txt => txt.value);//B1-4
  event.currentTarget.elements.all.value = texts.join(':');//C
  return false;//D
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 5vw/1.2 Consolas
}

input,
output {
  display: block;
  font: inherit
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name='text'>
  <input name='text'>
  <input name='text'>
  <output name='all'></output>
</form>
```